# Functors which induce isomorphisms on isomorphism-sets

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, higher-category-theory

Is there a name for functors $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ with the property that for all $A,B \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ the map $F : \mathrm{Isom}(A,B) \to \mathrm{Isom}(F(A),F(B))$ is an isomorphism? In other words, for every isomorphism $g : F(A) \to F(B)$ there is a unique isomorphism $f : A \to B$ with $g=F(f)$.

For example, the free functor $\mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}_*$, $X \mapsto (X+\{\star\},\star)$ has this property. From this example one can also see that $F$ does not have to be fully faithful.

Also note that $F$ does not have to be conservative, faithful, or full in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functors are precisely the pseudomonomorphisms in the 2-category of categories.

(A **pseudomonomorphism** is a morphism $f : X \to Y$ in a bicategory such that
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @= X \\
@| @VV{f}V \\
X @>>{f}> Y
\end{CD}$$
is a bicategorical pullback square.)

Comment: Learning never stops! Thank you.